# Inserir objetos numa Array sem copiar-los

Tags: .net, array, visual-basic-6, basic

Tem algum jeito de eu colocar os itens numa `Array` sem multiplica-los? Estou tentando o seguinte. Quero adicionar os itens da lista `MethodList` na lista `toAdd`, mas sem repetir o que há na lista `sourceItems`:

```
For Each iKey As String In MethodList
     For Each d As AutocompleteItem In mMenu.Items.sourceItems
        If Not (d.Text = iKey) Then ' Verifica se o item não existe na lista
           toAdd.Add(New AutocompleteItem(text:=iKey, 7))
        End If
     Next
Next
```

Mas não esta funcionando, ta mostrando assim na lista `toAdd`:

```
MeuObjeto
MeuObjeto
MeuObjeto
MeuObjeto
MeuObjeto
....
```

e  repetindo eles infinitamente, quero fazer com que não tenha o mesmo objeto na lista.

Comment: Você pode fazer algo assim: `If Not (mMenu.Items.sourceItems.contains(iKey)) Then`

Comment: Não funciona. `sourceItems` é uma lista de AutoCompleteItem, o objeto `iKey` é uma String, iria dar um conflito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o método de extensão [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) do `System.Linq`, da seguinte maneira:

```
For Each iKey As String In MethodList
    If Not toAdd.Any(Function(x) x.Text = iKey) Then
        toAdd.Add(New AutocompleteItem(text:=iKey, 7))
    End If
Next
```

O método `Any` com o parâmetro `Func(Of TSource, Boolean)`, retorna `True` se qualquer item da coleção satisfazer a condição passada. Nesse caso precisa negá-lo com o `Not` para inverter a condição.

---

Ou, se preferir, pode usar o [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), para não precisar negar o retorno do método:

```
For Each iKey As String In MethodList
    If toAdd.All(Function(x) x.Text <> iKey) Then 
        toAdd.Add(New AutocompleteItem(text:=iKey, 7))
    End If
Next
```

O `All`faz o inverso do `Any`, verificando se todos os itens da coleção satisfazem a condição. Nesse caso, se todos forem diferentes, então seu item não existe na lista.

---

Mais uma opção, para quem gosta de economizar linhas:

```
toAdd = MethodList.Distinct().Select(Function(x) New AutocompleteItem(x, 7)).ToList()
```

Nesta alternativa, primeiro é feito um [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) das strings e depois para cada uma é criado um objeto `AutocompleteItem` com o [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) e em seguida converte para [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) (estou supondo que `toAdd` é um `List(Of String)`).

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Abraço cara ^-^.

Comment: Adicionei mais uma alternativa, se preferir.

Comment: A primeira funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Ok, e acredito ter melhor desempenho do que a última. Estou deixando alternativas pois pode ajudar outras pessoas.